# Probability , one on uniform distribution

Tags: probability

Let X, Y be two random uniform variates in (0,1).  For $\alpha > 0$, find the probability $P(\max(X,Y) > \alpha \min(X,Y))$.

I tried like the below

$$P(\max(X,Y) > \alpha \min(X,Y)) = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} \int_{\alpha x}^{1} dy dx = \frac{1}{\alpha}$$

Should I multiply by 2 or not?

Someone verify the answer for me, pleasse.

Comment: Your answer is correct if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Otherwise you cannot determine this probability.

Comment: Thanks Sir, i really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0<\alpha\leqslant 1$ we have $\mathbb P(X\wedge Y>\alpha (X\vee Y))=1$, since $X>\alpha X$ and $Y>\alpha Y$. For $\alpha>1$ the region $$\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2: x\wedge y>\alpha (x\vee y)\}$$ is composed of two equilateral right triangles (one above and one below the line $x=y$). Plotting the region for sample values of alpha, we see that the first region $R_1$ is bounded by the $y$-axis, the line $y=1$, and the line $y=\alpha x$. Similarly, the second region $R_2$ is bounded by the $x$-axis, the line $x=1$, and the line $y=\frac1\alpha x$. The area of a right triangle is $\frac12 bh$ where $b$ is the base and $h$ the heigh. $R_1$ has a base $\frac1\alpha$ and height of $1$, so its area is $\frac12\cdot\frac1\alpha\cdot 1 =\frac1{2\alpha}$. By symmetry, the area of $R_2$ is also $\frac1{2\alpha}$, so the combined area is $$\frac1{2\alpha}+\frac1{2\alpha} = \frac1\alpha. $$

For problems like this I think it is more intuitive to think geometrically than to compute integrals. You are much more likely to make an error in setting up the integration bounds than reasoning with simple geometry. Of course, this approach is not always suitable, but it is a useful tool in cases like these.